# Override Existing Functionality Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting html from a server dynamically. When a user loads certain html I want to override the functionality of the listview filtering like this:

```
    $("#myList").listview('option', 'filterCallback', function (text, searchValue) {
    //console.log(text);  
    $("li[data-groupoptions]").removeClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
    $("li[data-groupoptions*="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]").addClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
});​
```

The problem is when I inject this code into my javascript it breaks all my javascript. I have a syntax issue here or I am not calling this right or something.

I want to add this code to this function I have in place

```
   function loadA() {

        ClearDescendant().success(function () {
            loadPage("apls", "alData", "alHeader", "alFooter");

         //ADD IT HERE????

        });
    }
```

How do I simply have this code available to run "in case" there is html on the page with a listview that has an id of "mylist" sometime "loadA()" doesnt return a listview with id "mylist" but the code is simply breaking besides that. I am not sure on how to call or where to put this code so its available when if html is returned from "loadPage()" that has "myList" in it

the code works fine here 
http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it break when you put the listview declaration inside a load handler function:

```
$("#myList").load( function() { 

     // insert listview override here.

});
```

Comment: @NickLaMarca - can you explain what you mean by "breaks"? The filtering part just doesn't run? If there is an error in the console, what line of your code does it complain about?